# cURL request causing form validation error

Tags: 8, forms

I'm working on a cURL request when a user submits an existing form to send some data to an outside service.

I've added this function with this line:
`$form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'my_module_push_data';`

And my cURL requests:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Get access token here
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://resturl.com&id=' . $id . '&secret=' . $secret);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $result = json_decode($result, true);

    // Then submit data
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://resturl.com/submit.json?access_token=' . $result['access_token']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($formData));
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $server_output = curl_exec($ch); // <--- This line causes issues
    $server_output = json_decode($server_output);
```

With this code, I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: "Form errors cannot be set after form validation has finished." at /mnt/gfs/.../.../docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormState.php
```

I've gone line by line through this cURL request and the line I marked (second `curl_exec()` causes this error. If I omit that line it works fine. The first `curl_exec()` works fine and I verified it's returning an access token.

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you!

EDIT: Full function (obfuscated some details)

```
/**
 * Custom submit handler to push data into Service
 */
function my_module_service_signup(array $form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $vals = $form_state->getValues();
    $formData = [];
    $myVals = [];

    $clientId = Settings::get('service_api_id');
    $clientSecret = Settings::get('service_api_secret');
    $accountId = 'abc123456';
    $formData['unique_id'] = '1234';

    $myVals = [
        'company' => $vals['field_company'][0]['value'],
        'firstName' => $vals['field_first_name'][0]['value'],
        'lastName' => $vals['field_last_name'][0]['value'],
        ...
    ];

    $formData['input'][0]['fields'] = $myVals;

    try {
        $getClient = \Drupal::httpClient();
        $request = $getClient->post('https://' . $accountId . '.resturl.com/get/token?my_id=' . $clientId . '&my_secret=' . $clientSecret);
        $response = json_decode($request->getBody());
    } catch(RequestException $e) {
    // The LogicException is not caught here
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show us the function that code exists in. Also, Drupal uses the Guzzle HTTP client for remote requests, which can be accessed with `\Drupal::httpClient()`.

Comment: @Jaypan I've made an edit with the full function (with some private details changed). I tried switching to using `\Drupal::httpClient()` this morning and it throws the same error. It seems to only throw the error when it receives a successful response from the endpoint. I'm able to see the response body in watchdog but it continues to throw this exception.

Comment: Are you sure that's where your error is coming from? What happens if you remove the request altogether just for testing?

Comment: @Jaypan Everything works fine if the request is removed. No errors logged in watchdog, the user account is created and the user is redirected to the backend of the site. Just commenting out the line with `$getClient->post()` resolves the issue.

Comment: Try catching `\Exception`, then using `watchdog_exception()` (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog_exception/9.2.x) to log the result. Maybe you can get more information from that.